# How to print just "Hello world" to connected printer with C# on windows?

Tags: c#, printing

The printer is an XPrinter XP-T58K model, and is conected to the computer, so i can just go to printers and print test page. I would like to know how to send a string to this printer with C#.

Comment: Which thermal printer?

Comment: Open Notepad. Type “Hello world”. Select File/Print. Select the thermal printer. Click Print.

Comment: Please be a bit more clear as to what you mean with "print" and what the "thermal receipt" is, also let us know what you have already tried yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a *Zpl / 2* enabled printer. The code would be

```
^XA
^FO100, 200
^AD,50,25
^FH_^FD Hello world^FS
^XZ
```

To print, send raw bytes directly to the printers *IP address* and port.

You can find the [full specs here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)

<sub>***Note** : A lot printers can be printed to directly (as mentioned in the comments)*</sub>